# Nginx Config for 2 django applications 2 different endpoints 1 server host

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

So the problem is I have 1 ip (**127.0.0.1** for example)

on my server lives 2 different django applications

```
1. /api     0.0.0.0:8000
2. /data    0.0.0.0:8090
3. /        this will go to default pages served up by nodejs
```

I need to figure out
the nginx configuration of how to deploy these separate services, each with its own database.

when navigating if an endpoint is hit, it will be routed to the appropriate app otherwise it will default to the nodejs app.

extra info:
when logging into /api/admin/ it gets routed to /admin and fails
please take into consideration redirections made by django.
I have tried a lot of things including setting Host, or Location

This will be a bounty in 2 days so happy hunting.

current nginx

```
upstream app1 {
    server 0.0.0.0:8000;
}

upstream app2 {
    server 0.0.0.0:8090;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;


    location / {
        error_log /var/log/webapp/error.log debug;
        access_log /var/log/webapp/access.log;

        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:3000;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /api {
        location /api/static {
            alias /var/tmp/app1/static;
            #autoindex on;
        }
        proxy_pass http://app1;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /data {
        location /data/static {
            alias /var/tmp/app2/static;
        }
        proxy_pass http://app2;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using docker?

Comment: can you share the full nginx config file

Comment: not using docker

Comment: I will sweeten the deal.... after 2 days, this question becomes eligible for a bounty. The accepted answer will get 75 points.

Comment: check this: https://serverfault.com/questions/956888/how-to-configure-multiple-servers-on-the-same-ip-address-with-nginx

Comment: It's not exactly clear what your problem is. What is your expected behaviour? And what is the behaviour now?

Comment: the problem is redirection within the django app. on /api/admin/ if you are not logged in, it tries to redirect you to http://localhost/admin/login/?next=/admin/ but fails

Comment: it should redirect you to http://localhost/api/admin/login/?next=/admin then it should put you into the django admin for that application /api/admin/

Comment: BTW, are these two Django app within the same Django codebase? If so, you don't need to deploy those separately.

Comment: no these are 2 separate codebases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using gunicorn as WSGI server ?

In case, try adding this to the existing nginx configuration:

```
location /api {
    proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /api;
    ...

location /data {
    proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /data;
    ...
...
```

In principle, SCRIPT_NAME will be passed to gunicorn, which in turn should use it as a prefix in all addresses.

I never tried this in a real project, though.

Comment: I have been traveling but will award the points and check your answer a little later. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Thank you. Let me know if this helps. If not, I'ld be interested on discussing this further

Comment: Hey Mario. Superb answer. I wish I could give you more kudos. I have setup a repo with the working example. https://github.com/bensialih/django_routing

Comment: Im looking into traefik as a possible solution as well

Comment: Glad it helped ;) Thank you for sharing a working example :clap: