# Configure an nginx proxy to two applications, a Flask and a Django, via two locations /v1 for Flask and /v2 for Django

Tags: django, nginx, proxy

I am hosting two Applications on same Server. A Flask App and a new Django App.
Flask is startet at local server 127.0.0.1:5000.
New Django App is startet at local server 127.0.0.1:8000.

In my nginx default Configuration File i added a new location Block for the new Django App and i try something like this:

```
# Nginx Config
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my-subdomain.my-domain.com;
    rewrite     ^   https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 default_server ssl;
    server_name 127.0.0.1;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-subdomain.my-domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-subdomain.my-domain.com/privkey.pem;

    # Old configuration before new Django App
    #location / {
    #    include proxy_params;
    #    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
    #}

    # Default location (version 1)
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    # Version 1 explicit
    location /v1 {
        rewrite ^/v1(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_redirect off;
        sub_filter 'href="/'  'href="/v1/';
        sub_filter_once off;
    }

    merge_slashes on;
    # Version 2
    location /v2 {
        rewrite ^/v2(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_redirect off;

        sub_filter 'href="/'  'href="/v2/';
        sub_filter_once off;
    }
}
```

Here is a View of my Django URLS Configuration:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("shortener/", include("urlshortener.urls")),
    path('projects/', include('projects.urls')),
]
```

Now the Problem is, when i access https://my-subdomain.my-domain.com/v2/admin
I get from Django :

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://my-subdomain.my-domain.com//admin #Notice the double Slashes
Using the URLconf defined in da_system_backend.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
shortener/
projects/
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, /admin, didn’t match any of these.
```

I tried:

- setting django APPEND_SLASH to False
- setting nginx  merge_slashes on;
- some nginx rewrites that did not solve anything

I even got to the point were the double slashes were removed, still Django can not find any of the URLS.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this Question worked for me as well.
[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69362436/nginx-config-for-2-django-applications-2-different-endpoints-1-server-host?rq=2)

Just adding `proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /v2;` to my `location /v2` Block in nginx configuration file, worked.